# How to use the Progressbar widget in real time

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter, widget

I have the following code that uses the Tkinter widget:

```
from Tkinter import *
from ttk import Progressbar

root = Tk()

def addThoseNumbers():
    y = 0
    for x in range(1000000):
        y += x
        if x % 10000.0 == 0:
            invoiceStatus['value'] = x/10000.0
    print y

invoiceStatus = Progressbar(root, length = 280, mode = 'determinate')
invoiceStatus.pack()
invoiceButton = Button(root, text = "Confirm", font = ("Helvetica", 10), \
command = addThoseNumbers)
invoiceButton.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Ideally, the progressbar would update while the program is working to show how much of the task has been completed, however it just cuts from 0% to 100% once the task has completed. How do I write my program so the progressbar shows the progress in real-time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add root.update()

```
from Tkinter import *
from ttk import Progressbar

root = Tk()

def addThoseNumbers():
    y = 0
    for x in range(1000000):
        y += x
        if x % 10000.0 == 0:
            invoiceStatus['value'] = x/10000.0
            root.update()
    print y

invoiceStatus = Progressbar(root, length = 280, mode = 'determinate')
invoiceStatus.pack()
invoiceButton = Button(root, text = "Confirm", font = ("Helvetica", 10), \
command = addThoseNumbers)
invoiceButton.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you! It's amazing how ive never heard of root.update until now